# Use sqldf to subset rows from column in a different data.frame

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

I'm translating some data.frame code into SQL by using sqldf. My goal here is to subset rows of a data.frame A using a column from B. Is this possible when A and B don't share any column names?

```
A = data.frame(a1 = c(1:4), a2 = c(101:104))
B = data.frame(b1 = c(1:2), b2 = c(55,56))

A[A$a1 %in% B$b1,]

##   a1  a2
## 1  1 101
## 2  2 102
```

I can subset A if I already know the values from B$b1, but that's not very scalable.

```
sqldf("select * from A where a1 in (1,2)")
```

Do I need an inner join and/or is it required to have identical column names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
fn$sqldf(" select * from A where a1 in ( `toString(B$b1)` ) ")
```

or

```
sqldf("select A.* from A join B on A.a1 = B.b1")
```

Answer (score 1):

We use paste twice. To concatenate the elements of the vector `B$b1` separated by commas. And then to concatenate the final text string desired: `[1] "select * from A where a1 in( 1,2 )"`

```
sqldf(paste("select * from A where a1 in(", paste(B$b1, collapse = ","), ")"))
```

Output:

```
  a1  a2
1  1 101
2  2 102
```